# in Chrome incorrect mouse coordinates transform for resizeable SVG (using viewport)

Tags: svg

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/alekzonder/j2ACr/5/

```
    var width = 960,  height = 500;

// Append an SVG element
var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + width + ' ' + height)
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

svg.append("rect")
.attr('id', 'followMe')
.attr('width', 20)
.attr('height', 20)
.attr('fill', 'peachPuff')
.attr('stroke', 'crimson');

var followRectElement = document.getElementById('followMe');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {

        var svgPoint = svg[0][0].createSVGPoint();

        svgPoint.x = event.clientX;
        svgPoint.y = event.clientY;

        svgPoint = svgPoint.matrixTransform(followRectElement.getScreenCTM().inverse());

        followRectElement.setAttribute('x', svgPoint.x - 10);
        followRectElement.setAttribute('y', svgPoint.y - 10);
    });
```

Cursor in center of rectangle on mousemove - Ok!

Not in center in Chrome - Bad

may be bug in getScreenCTM function (of svg element) in Chrome or not?

in Firefox, Opera all ok

Comment: I tested the script, try comment out the part of setting width and height property for first svg element. http://jsfiddle.net/86VXS/2/

Comment: @defghi1977 It works, you should make it an answer!  Also, any idea why?